# Java set maximum heap size (Xmx) as a fraction of physical memory

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

In [JDK 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html), The default maximum heap size is

> 1/4th of the physical memory or 1GB

And it can be overridden using the `-Xmx` switch:

> You can override this default using the -Xmx command-line option.

The `Xmx` switch works with *bytes*, not fractions. Is there a **straightforward** way of setting the maximum heap to X percent of the physical memory of a machine?

Edit:

Why, you ask? Well, first of all curiosity. I find it strange that the default Xmx is defined in terms of a fraction of the physical memory but as soon as I touch it then it' is suddenly an absolute value. Second, if I deploy the same (or similar) app to two different servers and one of them has more physical memory I'd like to have the option of automatically getting the JVM to take advantage of the extra memory. It doesn't always make sense, but sometimes it does.

The obvious solution is to use a shell script that checks the amount of free space and calculates the Xmx, but that seems like a clunky solution. I imagine it should be somehow possible with pure Java.

Comment: This is probably something you're going to have to do in whatever's invoking Java, and thus in a platform-dependent manner.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That's what I figured. But it's strange. The default is defined in terms of a fraction of physical memory, but there's no switch for changing the 1/4th to say 1/3 or 1/2.

Comment: Since you can't *change* the heap size of a HotSpot JVM, the "pure Java" solution is to use the techniques in the linked Q&A to find the physical memory size ... then launch a new JVM.  Frankly, you are better off with your "clunky" solution.

Comment: When you're setting the value, you are generally setting it based on knowing the amount your program actually needs. The JVM does not possess that insight, so it makes a 'guess' based on how much physical memory exists. It's unclear that you, the user, needs to guess.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since [Java 8u191 (October 16, 2018)](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u191-relnotes.html), there are three dedicated JVM options to control the heap size as a fraction of the available memory. They are documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

Note that contrary to what its name suggests, `MinRAMPercentage` also controls the **maximum** heap size

> **-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=percent**
>
> Sets the initial amount of memory that the JVM will use for the Java heap before applying ergonomics heuristics as a percentage of the maximum amount determined as described in the -XX:MaxRAM option. The default value is 1.5625 percent.
>
> **-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=percent**
>
> Sets the maximum amount of memory that the JVM may use for the Java heap before applying ergonomics heuristics as a percentage of the maximum amount determined as described in the -XX:MaxRAM option. The default value is 25 percent.
>
> **-XX:MinRAMPercentage=percent**
>
> Sets the maximum amount of memory that the JVM may use for the Java heap before applying ergonomics heuristics as a percentage of the maximum amount determined as described in the -XX:MaxRAM option for small heaps. A small heap is a heap of approximately 125 MB. The default value is 50 percent.

Here are some example runs using docker on x64 using jdk 11u10:

`docker run --memory <limit> openjdk:11 java -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=25 -XX:MinRAMPercentage=50 -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=5 -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal 2>&1 | grep HeapSize`

```
| Memory Limit | Initial Heap Size | Max Heap Size    |
|--------------|-------------------|------------------|
| 100Mi        | 10485760 (~10%)   | 52428800 (~50%)  |
| 256Mi        | 27262976 (~10%)   | 132120576 (~50%) |
| 512Mi        | 54525952 (~10%)   | 134217728 (~25%) |
| 1Gi          | 109051904 (~10%)  | 268435456 (~25%) |
```

Comment: Great solution! Please note, with OpenJDK you need version 10 for this. https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8219312 Quick check: `java -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=25 -version`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to do it yourself. Say you're going for a windows version,
get the max amount of Memory ( parse something like `wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory` ) , calculate 1/4 of this and set it as the -Xmx option...

I would like to ask you why you'd need a percentage of the physical memory. The max amount of memory shouldnt affect the memory usage of your application, and if so the application should handle it itself

Comment: To the question "I would like to ask you why you'd need a percentage of the physical memory". An example might be a game with a variable render distance. If not much memory is available it will choose a small render distance. But if lots of memory is available then a large render distance can be chosen